# XML-RPC Standard and XML Data Type

Tags: web-services, language-agnostic, soap, cross-platform, xml-rpc

I was looking at XML-RPC for a project. And correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like XML-RPC has no XML datatype. Are you supposed to pass as a string? or something else?

Am I missing something? Looks like this was though of with SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language you are using you can work with different data types. This is for JAVA.

[Here are all the data types among xml-rpc](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/types.html)

One of them is the org.w3c.dom.Node. Which can be your xml.

Although IMHO. You don't need to have a data type of a xml. Take a look at the [example on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC#Data_types)

Comment: I'm confused about your last sentence. What if I know a parameter on a call is XML, but I don't have any other guarantees on its structure? I can't break it down into other primitives.

Comment: If you have a parameter like a XML it should look like this <xml><firstNode><secondNode>ItsValue</secondNode></firstNode>

you can use instead of it the datatypes of firstNode and secondNode. Although you are probably right thinking a xml datatype would turn it easier.

I dont see any case where you cant substitute it by the other data types (probably with <string> and <value> on most of the cases).

Also that's a little biased comment since I dont really like xml-rpc

Comment: I guess you could do <XmlInformation><string><doc>some schemaless doc</doc></string></XmlInformation> not sure if <string> values are supposed to contain XML (and at that XML unescaped)